# Is OpenID Connect the right tool to allow a embedded 3rd webapp/site (in an iframe) to be automatically logged in?

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect

We have a WebApp to which we want to allow 3rd parties to add UI extensions by means of embedding their 3rd party WebApp in an iframe, much like SalesForce Canvas of WeChat Mini Programs.

One of the particulars we're having difficulties with is figuring out how to provide a seamless UX, in the sense that when the user is already logged into our WebApp and they browse to a place where a 3rd party webapp is embedded, there should be no login required to gain access to the 3rd party webapp.

I have the feeling that OpenID Connect would be helpful here. I've found some references online which say that one of the (cool) things you can do with the id_token received is pass it onto a 3rd party app, but I have a difficult time finding more info on that, how exactly you'd have to do the passing/what the flow would be and what security things you'd have to consider when doing so.

Did find this in the specs: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ThirdPartyInitiatedLogin, which seems to indicate OpenId Connect supports it, but I can find little to no further info on this

So, am looking for confirmation that OpenId Connect is the right approach and then pointers on how to achieve it.

TIA, Paul

Answer (score 0):

You may use OpenID Connect indeed: upon loading the iframe you would redirect the user to the OpenID Connect provider with an authorization request that is specific for the 3rd-party app (i.e. the 3rd party app is a Client/RP on it own).

The 3rd-party app would get its own `id_token` in the response.

Comment: hi Hans, tnx for your answer, however I still not fully comprehend the involved flow.

I understand that we control the 3rd party app url that gets opened and the 3rd party app admin could supply that when registering their app with us.

But how to make sure that the 3rd party app can determine which user is the one logged into our app and then seamlessly log that user into their app, without a login screen?

I have the feeling I must be passing some info from my webapp into the url that gets loaded into the iframe, but having trouble to see how/what exactly.

Hope you can elaborate

Comment: Think I partially figured it out:  
- the 3rd party app needs to support a login deeplink url (registered under the initiate_login_uri property)  
  
- We load that url into the iframe with an 'iss' query parameter with the value of the OP we use appended to it (and optionally 'login_hint' and 'target_link_uri' query params)  
  
- the 3rd party app make an authentication request to the OP suggested in the 'iss' query parameter  
  
The bit I don't quite get is how the OP knows the user to authenticate for the 3rd party RP and how this is a secure process.